# how to set the value of input textbox based upon the selected value of select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image][image]ironically this is working it is showing the correct value but not in the value attribute of the input textbox; and neither anything is displayed in the textbox

when i inspected my web page on google chrome
the code of the input tag was

```
<input name="leave_allowed" class="form-control" id="leave_allowed" value="">15</input>
```

here 15 is my desired outcome but it should be displayed within the value attribute
KINDLY HELP ME

here is my select list which is getting values from db

```
<span class="span_error"><?echo $error_cmp_id;?></span>
 <select name="ddl_ofc" size="1"  class="form-control" id="ddl_ofc" onchange="getleaveid(this.value);">
    <option value="0" disabled selected=''>Select Leave Type</option>
```

here is my code of input textbox

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Leaves Allowed*</label>
   <span class="span_error"></span>
     <input name="leave_allowed" class="form-control" id="leave_allowed" value="">
    </div>
```

here is the jquery function

```
     function getleaveid(id)
  {
    //alert(id);
   // $('#leave_allowed').val("Select From the DropDown Above");
     $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"getdata.php",
      data:{leaveid:id},
      success:function(data)
      {
          $('#leave_allowed').val(data);
      }

  });
  }
```

here is the getdata.php file

```
 function get_total_leaves_allowed($leaveid)
 {
 $query_leave="SELECT * from leave_type where leave_type_id='$leaveid'";
   $result_leave=mysql_query($query_leave);
    $rl=mysql_fetch_array($result_leave);
   $leaves_allowed=$rl['leave_allowed'];
 echo $leaves_allowed;

 }

   if(isset($_POST['leaveid']))
 {
   $leaveid =$_POST['leaveid'];
   get_total_leaves_allowed($leaveid);
  }
```

Comment: It is fine. What happens if you change `$('#leave_allowed').val(id)` with `$('#leave_allowed').attr('value', id)`? And You missed the `type="text"` in the `<input>` tag

Comment: You should really add a `type` attribute on your input-field.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude its still not working i dont want id i want $leaves_allowed there

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i missed it accidentally but still its not working same as before its showing the value when i inspect it but not in the value attribute

Comment: Sorry, `id` is `data`. But you must understand it....

Comment: @TalhaSarwar you will not see the value attribute filled. To know if it's working, put in your console `$('#leave_allowed').val()` and you'll see the correct result. Your code works fine. At least if you don't have more code that causes conflict

Comment: I don't think it will change something, but the correct way to close an input is /> and not </input> :)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude can i show you the screenshot

Comment: Yeah, share a screenshot with the result in the console.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude i have shared a screenshot

Comment: @Knriano brother see the input text box code which i have shared above

Comment: @Knriano i havent closed the input tag like this </input> it happened dynamically when i selected a value from select box

Comment: Ok, did you try Marcos's solution $('#leave_allowed').attr('value', data) ? Same error?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude yes brother still the same issue

Comment: @Knriano still the same issue brother

Comment: Actually @Knriano is right, you are not closing the input properly, and I'm not talking about what happens dinamically, I'm talking about your code! You have `<input name="leave_allowed" class="form-control" id="leave_allowed" value="">` but instead you need `<input name="leave_allowed" class="form-control" id="leave_allowed" value="" />` the difference is the `/` at the end

Comment: You can try this: https://jsfiddle.net/3tum7e6j/ It's not the best solution but it should work in your case I hope

Comment: @mastazi that's optional, not mandatory. It doesn't make any difference

Comment: @TalhaSarwar I think you have a code that makes conflict. Please, try to reproduce the issue with a minimal example in jsfiddle.net or stacksnippets

Comment: There are some (unrelated) issues with your PHP-code. 1. You really shouldn't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) which you can protect yourself against by using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). If your using MySQLi or PDO, that is.

Comment: @Knriano thankx alot that worked thankx alot